# JavaScript ReferenceError of an already declared Identifier

Tags: javascript

I've been playing around with JavaScript to learn some concepts, and stumbled across this small example.

Consider the function:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(x);
}
```

and then, run:

```
> foo(); let x = 10;
```

I get the expected:

```
ReferenceError: x is not defined
    at foo (repl:2:13)
```

But, surprisingly, I neither cannot define `x`

```
> let x = 10;
SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been declared
```

nor reassign it

```
> x = 10;
ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

Is this behavior expected? What's the state of `x`?

**Edit:**

Example on Google Chrome:

[image: Example on Google Chrome]

Comment: Are you trying this out inside the browser? Because this does not make sense when you try this out on an actual editor apart from re-declaring it.

Comment: @RohitKashyap Tried it inside of Chrome and in Node, same behavior

Comment: @charlietfl the issue is that the state of the scope of Chrome's console and Node is (or looks like) broken: it doesn't let me declare `x` or use it again.

Comment: It's true that you cannot declare it again, but the reassigning works fine on my machine.

Comment: @RohitKashyap did you run this as a one-liner? `foo(); let x = 10;`

Comment: Yes I did and it works fine.

Comment: @RohitKashyap Tried on Safari, same behavior. Did you run it on Firefox?

Comment: Ran it on chrome.

Comment: @RohitKashyap can you take a look at this, to see if it's the same? https://i.imgur.com/5c3106O.png

Comment: @nicodp I see this same behaviour on chrome.

Comment: "*Is this behavior expected?*" - Yes. "*What's the state of x?*" `x is not defined` is not a good error message. It should be `x was not initialised` or `x is uninitialised`.

Comment: @Bergi: yes, but why does `x = 10` throw? Can an assignment ever throw?

Comment: @georg Yes, any usage of an uninitialised variable does throw. Just like it does in `{ x = 10; let x; }`. (Although the error message for that is much better: `Cannot access 'x' before initialization`).

Comment: @Bergi so if I understand correctly, the `let x` gets hoisted, the call to `foo` throws the error so `x` never gets initialized. But why you can't reassign it thereafter?

Comment: @Bergi: so Firefox is wrong? https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpqeH.png

Comment: @georg Looks like it, yes. Or put in other words: it might have a more user-friendly debugger console, which is able to clean up redeclaration mistakes. Or maybe it runs the latter lines in different scopes. Who knows.

Comment: @nicodp "*But why you can't reassign it thereafter?*" - because it's still declared and uninitialised. See the duplicate for more explanation of this behaviour.

Comment: @Bergi the answer made things clear, thanks!